# My Setup runs well (in update), but no component is updated

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

There is something fundamental I miss about running an upgrade.

I've a setup (setup.exe) with embedded MSI, authored by InstallShield. When running the setup on a clean machine - everything installs perfectly.

When running a higher version setup (in my case: 3.6.200) on a machine that has a lower version setup installed (3.5.300) - the setup is running fine, it even says that the software was updated to the new version 3.6.200 - but I ended up with the exact same files - No components was updated.

I've double checked the file version - and they are set correctly (3.5.300.0 and 3.6.200.0) for all binaries. For both versions I've the same 'Product Code' and 'Upgrade Code', which I believe this is what I should do.

Two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What diagnostics tools do I have? Is there any verbose mode where Setup or InstallShield can tell my why it didn't upgrade my components?

Comment: Did you log and read the installer upgrade log?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - apologize, not very familiar with Setup/Installshield. How do I log, and where are the installer upgrade log?

Comment: Did you generate an MSI or an EXE (self extracting containing MSI)?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - it is setup.exe.

Comment: StackOVerflow is formatting my comment. That's /l star v

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Surround it with backtics like in regular post: `setup.exe /v"/l*v upgrade.log"` or `setup.exe /s /v"/qn /l*v upgrade.log"`

Comment: Ugh :)  Thank you though!

Comment: This will work only if the setup.exe does and install with REINSTALLMODE and REINSTALL properties set, because that's the only way to upgrade a product with the same Product and Upgrade codes. If so, then you probably removed a component, and that will cause the update to go into advertised mode and no files will be updated. Look for SELMGR in the log and warnings about removing components during an update. Otherwise, did you intend a major upgrade? Not with the same ProductCode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uri,

Hopefully you have found a solution to the problem by now. 
One of the things to consider is the difference between a minor and major upgrade. MSDN has great documentation on the difference between these two.

Phil asks in his comment if you intended this to be a major upgrade. If you want this to be a major upgrade then you do want to change your ProductCode GUID. Based on what you wrote, you are currently configured for a minor upgrade. This is usually used so that you can create patch packages for an existing setup.

Christopher was trying to help you figure out how to create a MSI log file that will list all of the actions taken when upgrading. If you have the log file then try parsing through the output or place here if appropriate as a zip file. If it has sensitive data make sure you remove that first. You also can set msi logging parameters in the registry. Just search for 'voicewarmup msi logging' in google for examples of the policy key to set.

The only thing that I can think of that can happen in your scenario is that the key file association for components did not get setup correctly. The MSI engine uses the version of the key file associated with a component to determine if the file should be replaced during a minor upgrade. If you do not specify a key file then the component directory is used to evaluate if the file should be upgraded. So in a minor upgrade scenario if the component directory is [INSTALLDIR] and it already exists then the files will never be updated.

If this is the case then I believe you will need to change the ProductCode and build a major upgrade. Make sure you follow the component rules of one 'exe, dll, ocx, or chm' file per component and set that particular file as the key file for the component. 
Also a tip, avoid using dynamic links in InstallShield and if you do never use the include sub directories. This can lead to problems with patching and upgrades.